# HTML5 Websocket client listens changes in SQL Server 2014

Tags: c#, sql-server, websocket

I apologise for my bad English in advance. I have 200 POE (Power Over Ethernet) devices which are working as web client (browser). They are mounted at hospital doctor rooms' doors and displaying information about the doctor and patient que number.

POEs are requesting to server for any changes in data by their IP address once in 20 seconds by AJAX and server responses for the result. But I want to change application as Websocket supported architecture. I want my clients (POEs) to listen server (if possible directly to SQL Server) for changes. I am wondering that if there is a way to message client by using a SQL Server trigger.

I have seen some questions similar but could not find my answer yet. I would like you kindly share your knowledge with me and recommend some solutions for my approach. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using SignalR?

Comment: No I didn't. Do you suggest?

Comment: I would try. i use it and I'm pretty happy with it.

Comment: Thank you very much Ricky, after your suggestion I got it SignalR is better option for my purpose. There is very nice sample exactly matching my purpose at link. https://gkulshrestha.wordpress.com/